# Cannot find primary outlet error when selecting the browser back button

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting the following error when I go into a child route and then select the browser back button to go backwards. I have researched this error and do not seem to have any of the issues described. For example all my parent routes have a router-outlet. What is also interesting is the error is intermittent. It does not always happen but happens eventually.

**Error:**

[image]

*I set up my project and routes as follows:*

**Application Routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/start/landing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'start',
    component: StartComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'landing', component: LandingPage }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'signup-login',
    component: SignupLoginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'email-login', component: EmailLoginPage },
      { path: 'linkedin-login', component: LinkedinLoginPage },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'devices', component: DevicesPage },
      { path: 'device/:id', component: DeviceDetailsPage },

      { path: 'groups', component: GroupsPage },
      { path: 'group/:id', component: GroupDetailsPage },
      { path: 'group-score', component: GroupScorePage },
      { path: 'group-devices', component: GroupDevicesPage },
      { path: 'group-members', component: GroupMembersPage },
      { path: 'group-invite-member', component: GroupInviteMemberPage },

      { path: 'sites', component: SitesPage },
      { path: 'site/:id', component: SiteDetailsPage },
      { path: 'site-score', component: SiteScorePage },
      { path: 'site-devices', component: SiteDevicesPage },
      { path: 'site-tenants', component: SiteTenantsPage },
      { path: 'site-invite-tenant', component: SiteInviteTenantPage },

      { path: 'profile', component: ProfilePage },
      { path: 'cyber-score', component: CyberScorePage },
      { path: '', component: DevicesPage }
    ]
  }
];
```

**App Component HTML:**

```
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <notifications></notifications>
</main>
```

**Dashboard Component HTML:**

```
<section class="dashboard">
  <toolbar class="main"></toolbar>
  <header class="dashboard-header">
    <div class="dashboard-profile-info">
      <a routerLink="/dashboard/profile" routerLinkActive="active">
        <i class="material-icons">face</i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-cyber-score">
      <a routerLink="/dashboard/cyber-score" routerLinkActive="active">
        <div class="dashboard-cyber-score-display">
          <img class="score-image" src="/img/score.png" alt="">
          <span>My Cyber Score</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="dashboard-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</section>
```

App Module:

```
// Application Dependencies
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Application Pages
/* Public Pages */
import { LandingPage } from './pages/public/landing.page';
import { EmailLoginPage } from './pages/public/email-login.page';
import { LinkedinLoginPage } from './pages/public/linkedin-login.page';
import { PageNotFoundPage } from './pages/public/page-not-found.page';

/* Private Pages */
import { DevicesPage } from './pages/authenticated/devices.page';
import { DeviceDetailsPage } from './pages/authenticated/device-details.page';

import { GroupsPage } from './pages/authenticated/groups.page';
import { GroupDetailsPage } from './pages/authenticated/group-details.page';
import { GroupScorePage } from './pages/authenticated/group-score.page';
import { GroupDevicesPage } from './pages/authenticated/group-devices.page';
import { GroupMembersPage } from './pages/authenticated/group-members.page';
import { GroupInviteMemberPage } from './pages/authenticated/group-invite-member.page';

import { SitesPage } from './pages/authenticated/sites.page';
import { SiteDetailsPage } from './pages/authenticated/site-details.page';
import { SiteScorePage } from './pages/authenticated/site-score.page';
import { SiteDevicesPage } from './pages/authenticated/site-devices.page';
import { SiteTenantsPage } from './pages/authenticated/site-tenants.page';
import { SiteInviteTenantPage } from './pages/authenticated/site-invite-tenant.page';

import { CyberScorePage } from './pages/authenticated/cyber-score.page';
import { ProfilePage } from './pages/authenticated/profile.page';

// Application Modules
import { RoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';

/* ======== testing ======== */
// import { TestingModule } from './modules/testing/testing.module';
/* ======== testing ======== */

// Application Components
/* Site Components */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './components/site/toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './components/site/notifications/notifications.component';
/* Parent Page Components */
import { StartComponent } from './pages/public/start/start.component';
import { SignupLoginComponent } from './pages/public/signup-login/signup-login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/authenticated/dashboard/dashboard.component';
/* Page Components */
import { LandingComponent } from './components/pages/landing/landing.component';
import { EmailLoginComponent } from './components/pages/email-login/email-login.component';
import { LinkedinLoginComponent } from './components/pages/linkedin-login/linkedin-auth.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

import { DevicesComponent } from './components/pages/devices/devices.component';
import { DeviceDetailsComponent } from './components/pages/devices/device-details.component';

import { GroupsComponent } from './components/pages/groups/groups.component';
import { GroupDetailsComponent } from './components/pages/groups/group-details.component';
import { GroupScoreComponent } from './components/pages/groups/group-score.component';
import { GroupDevicesComponent } from './components/pages/groups/group-devices.component';
import { GroupMembersComponent } from './components/pages/groups/group-members.component';
import { GroupInviteMemberComponent } from './components/pages/groups/group-invite-member.component';

import { SitesComponent } from './components/pages/sites/sites.component';
import { SiteScoreComponent } from './components/pages/sites/site-score.component';
import { SiteDetailsComponent } from './components/pages/sites/site-details.component';
import { SiteDevicesComponent } from './components/pages/sites/site-devices.component';
import { SiteTenantsComponent } from './components/pages/sites/site-tenants.component';
import { SiteInviteTenantComponent } from './components/pages/sites/site-invite-tenant.component';

import { CyberScoreComponent } from './components/pages/cyber-score/cyber-score.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/pages/profile/profile.component';

// Application Services
import { Env } from '../_env';
import { removeNgStyles, createNewHosts } from '@angularclass/hmr';
import { HttpHeaders } from './shared/services/http-headers';
import { SessionStorage } from './shared/services/session-storage';
import { Notifications } from './components/site/notifications/notifications.service';

import { InviteTenantHttp } from './components/pages/sites/site-invite-tenant-http.service';
import { GroupsHttp } from './components/pages/groups/groups-http.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    // Custom Modules
    AuthModule,
    // TestingModule,
    // Routing
    RoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    // Parent Page Components
    StartComponent,
    SignupLoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    // Public Pages
    LandingPage,
    LandingComponent,
    EmailLoginPage,
    EmailLoginComponent,
    LinkedinLoginPage,
    LinkedinLoginComponent,
    PageNotFoundPage,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    // Private Pages
    ProfilePage,
    ProfileComponent,
    DevicesPage,
    DevicesComponent,
    DeviceDetailsPage,
    DeviceDetailsComponent,
    /* Groups */
    GroupsPage,
    GroupsComponent,
    GroupDetailsPage,
    GroupDetailsComponent,
    GroupScorePage,
    GroupScoreComponent,
    GroupDevicesPage,
    GroupDevicesComponent,
    GroupMembersPage,
    GroupMembersComponent,
    GroupInviteMemberPage,
    GroupInviteMemberComponent,
    /* Sites */
    SitesPage,
    SitesComponent,
    SiteDetailsPage,
    SiteDetailsComponent,
    SiteScorePage,
    SiteScoreComponent,
    SiteDevicesPage,
    SiteDevicesComponent,
    SiteTenantsPage,
    SiteTenantsComponent,
    SiteInviteTenantPage,

    SiteInviteTenantComponent,

    CyberScorePage,
    CyberScoreComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Env,
    HttpHeaders,
    InviteTenantHttp,
    GroupsHttp,
    Notifications,
    SessionStorage
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})

export class AppModule {

  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {}

  hmrOnInit(store) {
    console.log('HMR store', store);
  }

  hmrOnDestroy(store) {
    let cmpLocation = this.appRef.components.map(cmp => cmp.location.nativeElement);
    // recreate elements
    store.disposeOldHosts = createNewHosts(cmpLocation);
    // remove styles
    removeNgStyles();
  }

  hmrAfterDestroy(store) {
    // display new elements
    store.disposeOldHosts();
    delete store.disposeOldHosts;
  }
}
```

Updated: Complete Error:

I changed the structure of my application since this ticket was initially created so dashboard is no longer there and has been changed. But the error is still the same.

```
VM51267:48 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FrameworkComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'FrameworkComponent'
    at getOutlet (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:1003:19)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:877:30)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:860:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:859:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:852:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:579:56)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:108:21)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:232:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:174:27)
    at Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:2910:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ReduceSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:764:1), <anonymous>:105:30)
    at ReduceSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:125:30)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:241:1), <anonymous>:116:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at ReduceOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:764:1), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:41:1), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:2910:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at EverySubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1225:1), <anonymous>:47:26)
    at EverySubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1225:1), <anonymous>:64:14)
    at EverySubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:125:30)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:241:1), <anonymous>:116:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at EveryOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1225:1), <anonymous>:27:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:41:1), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:2910:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:41:1), <anonymous>:16:25)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at LastSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1928:1), <anonymous>:109:25)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:404:1), <anonymous>:94:30)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1183:1), <anonymous>:51:28)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:404:1), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at LastOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1928:1), <anonymous>:38:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CatchOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1190:1), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:352:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:411:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:87:38)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Observable.forEach (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:86:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:562:18)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Router.runNavigate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:514:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:497:1), <anonymous>:493:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:232:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1060:1), <anonymous>:238:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:231:32)
    at Zone.run (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:114:43)
    at eval (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:502:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:5719/js/vendor.js:1060:1), <anonymous>:229:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:264:40)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:401:35)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:339:25)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (eval at 931 (http://localhost:5719/js/polyfills.js:1451:1), <anonymous>:970:25)
```

Comment: Can you add AppModule code also.

Comment: I added it. Please excuse all the imports. I did this once with out and the person wanted to see them later.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't, its really an annoying issue because I cannot find anything wrong with my code. I am updating the file with the entire error. Do you have any idea what is causing this. It seem like whenever I leave a view open for awhile and then later select the back button this happens.

Comment: This also happens regardless of whether I use the browser back button or a back button within the application using this.location.back();

Comment: A bit more insight, this is only happening for me when I lazy load a module. If you see https://plnkr.co/edit/lhOZAf6d3YhtA7n3i8Zz?p=preview, back works just fine...